# How to get the current text after each key press in a Winforms TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I am trying to filter a list of items in a `ListView` as the user types into a `TextBox` and I use `KeyDown`, and `KeyPress` events but when I read the `textbox.Text`, it always returns the text before the last key press. Is there a way to always get whatever is shown in the `TextBox` without pressing enter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`TextBox.TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event (inherited from `Control`).

> Occurs when the Text property value changes.

My advice is to try not to hack this with the key events (down / press / up) - there are other ways to change a text-box's text, such as by pasting text from the right-click context menu. This doesn't involve pressing a key.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I thought textchanged only fires on enter, focus change, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `TextChanged` event of the TextBox in question. I think the `KeyUp` event might work as well.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers are incomplete with regards to the actual original question: how to retrieve the contents of the `Text` property when the user has just pressed a key (and including that keypress)?

The `KeyUp` event happens to be fired **AFTER** the contents of the `Text` property actually change, so using this particular order of events, you can retrieve the latest value of the text contents just using a `KeyUp` event handler.

The `KeyPress` event doesn't work because that gets fired **BEFORE** the change of the `Text` property.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static string NextControlValue(string originalValue, int selectStart, int selectLength, string keyChar)
    {
        if (originalValue.Length > selectStart)
        {
            if (selectLength > 0)
            {
                originalValue = originalValue.Remove(selectStart, selectLength);
                return NextControlValue(originalValue, selectStart, 0, keyChar);
            }
            else
            {
                return originalValue.Insert(selectStart, keyChar);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return originalValue + keyChar;
        }

    }

var previewValue = NextControlValue(textbox.Text, textbox.SelectionStart, textbox.SelectionLength, e.KeyChar + "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **KeyPress** event:

```
int position = textBox1.SelectionStart;
string changedText = textBox1.Text.Insert(position, e.KeyChar.ToString());
```