# How to save the as I type in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a textbox where the user inputs a string like "Joe was here" and that same string is "written" on the text file at the same time. Most of the questions asked around is using a button that helps save the string to the text file.

It works great, however for some unknown reason the text file can't register the last key pressed. In other words if I wrote "Joe was here" in my textbox, the text file has "Joe was her" where the "e" is missing.It's always the last key :(

This is a general view of the code I have that makes it work

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Dim File_name As String = "path where text file is saved at"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(File_name) Then
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(File_name)

        objWriter.Write(TextBox1.Text)
        objWriter.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

Maybe I'm missing something? Perhaps I'm using the wrong type of event as I'm using keypress instead of keydown or something else?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8955453/2278086) - basically it suggests to handle TextChanged instead (e.g. to catch text pasted in with the mouse).

Comment: @Mark: Oh, this can come in handy indeed! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just did a quick sample with your code and gives the exact issue, so i changed to the event keyup and it worked.

reason could be the time that keypress event processes or receives the key code at least in keyup first receive all the text and then executes the call to the process.

Comment: It would seem so that the keyup event is the solution to it. Nice explanation as to why by the way. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\test.txt", TextBox1.Text, False)
End Sub
```